# What does "vanilla" mean?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, terminology, gradient-descent

In machine learning blogs I frequently encounter the word "vanilla". For example, "Vanilla Gradient Descent" or "Vanilla method". This term is literally never seen in any optimization textbooks.

For instance, in this [post](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/introduction-to-gradient-descent-algorithm-along-its-variants/), it says:

> This is the simplest form of gradient descent technique. Here, vanilla
>   means pure / without any adulteration. Its main feature is that we
>   take small steps in the direction of the minima by taking gradient of
>   the cost function.

Pray tell, what does "adulteration" mean in this context? The author goes further by contrasting vanilla gradient descent with gradient descent with momentum. So in this case vanilla gradient descent is another word for gradient descent.

In another [post](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/), it says,

> Vanilla gradient descent, aka batch gradient descent,...

Sadly I have never heard of batch gradient descent either. Oh boy.

Can someone clarify what "vanilla" means and if there is a firmer mathematical definition to it?

Comment: This isn't technical jargon -- the term is being used in an ordinary idiomatic-English sense (See def 2 [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vanilla) or [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vanilla#Adjective) or [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=vanilla+definition)). While the question is on topic here on CV it might go better on English.SE or ELL.SE (English language learners, if English is not your first language).

Comment: Without adornment. As in vanilla ice cream.

Comment: @Glen_b From an outsider's perspective, many things can look like technical jargon ;)

Comment: No doubt -- this is why I was explaining it.

Comment: @Glen_b As far as I know, vanilla in the software industry is just a technical term, which comes from the traditional standard flavor of ice cream, vanilla. see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Vanilla means standard, usual, or unmodified version of something. Vanilla gradient descent means the basic gradient descent algorithm without any bells or whistles.

There are many variants on gradient descent. In usual gradient descent (also known as batch gradient descent or vanilla gradient descent), the gradient is computed as the average of the gradient of each datapoint.

$$\nabla f = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i \nabla \text{loss}(x_i)$$

In stochastic gradient descent with a batch size of one, we might estimate the gradient as

$$\nabla f \approx \nabla \text{loss}(x^*)$$, where $x^*$ is randomly sampled from our entire dataset. It is a variant of normal gradient descent, so it wouldn't be vanilla gradient descent. However, since even stochastic gradient descent has many variants, you might call this "vanilla stochastic gradient descent", when comparing it to other fancier SGD alternatives, for example, SGD with momentum.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a word to describe "standard gradient descent" and didn't really want to use vanilla

Comment: Thanks for the clarification I was about to go insane with all those random appearances of the word next to technical terms.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, anyone knows why is called "vanilla" though?

Comment: well as for the etymology, i found this excellent answer -- https://english.stackexchange.com/a/451866

Comment: And what does "without any bells or whistles" mean? ;-)

Comment: @IgorF. it's an idiom which means "items or features that are useful or decorative but not essential". https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bells%20and%20whistles

Comment: @shimao Thanks. My tongue-in-cheek comment (which obviously wasn't received as such) was that you explained one idiom with another one.